# Cannot define step definition in cucumber

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, bdd

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM2Ey.png)

I am trying to create step definition from the feature file, but the steps in feature file does not get highlighted even if i press alt+enter. (Please refer to the image and ignore the ":")

But the same was working a couple of days back, so not sure whether I messed up something.

Please let me know my mistake

Comment: Is there are runner class defined somewhere where the glue is specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i figured out the problem. I had installed a cucumber.js few month back which was causing the problem. I uninstalled cucmber.js though my IDE and then just used cucumber java and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this issue in the future, you can try some other cucumber editor like `Cucumber Eclipse Plugin 1.0.0.202005150629` or `Natural 0.9`